# Load RTE into custom module for use in control panel

Tags: control-panel, add-on-development, rte

is there a way to load the RTE javascript in a module for the cpanel?

I have tried the following, but keep getting an error when refreshing the page:

```
ee()->load->library(array('javascript', 'rte_lib'));

ee()->javascript->output(
  ee()->rte_lib->build_js(0, '.WysiHat-field', NULL, TRUE)
);
```

error:
`Unable to load the requested class: rte_lib`

any ideas?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the package path for the RTE module first:

```
ee()->load->add_package_path(PATH_MOD.'rte/');
```

Comment: i figured that out just before you posted this, but thanks :)